# Llenar Select en Html desde la base de datos de Firebase teniendo en cuenta el valor de otro Select

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, select

Necesito llenar un select cargado desde una base de datos de Firebase, pero que éste se llene dependiendo de la opción que se seleccione en otro select que es llenado con un Array.

Intenté usar un `if()` pero no supe hacerlo o no me resultó.

Agradezco de antemano su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el HTML:

```
<div class="realizar-pedidos">
<select id="tipo-ped" >
    <option></option>
</select>

<select id="pedido">
    <option></option>
</select>
</div>
```

Aquí está el código JS:

```
 var db = firebase.firestore();

   // LLENAR EL PRIMER SELECT

   let menuTiposPlatos = ["Desayunos", "Almuerzos", "Cena"]

   let menuTipos = document.getElementById('tipo-ped');

   function Recorrer(menuTipos, valores){
      
       for(let i of valores){
           menuTipos.innerHTML+= `
           <option>${i}</option>
           `
      }
   }

   function llenarTipos(){
       Recorrer(menuTipos, menuTiposPlatos);
   }
   llenarTipos()


//LLENAR EL SEGUNDO SELECT SEGUN LA OPCION DEL PRIMERO Y LA BASE DE DATOS
  
        let tipoPed = document.getElementById('pedido');//Se llama el selected
   
    
            tipoPed.innerHTML = '';
            tipoPed.innerHTML += `
                    <option value="0" selected>Selecciona</option>
                    ` //Agrego un option por default
                    db.collection("MENU")
                    .get()
                    .then((querySnapshot) => {
                        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
                            tipoPed.innerHTML += `
                            <option value="${doc.id}">${doc.data().platillo}</option> . 
                            ` //Aquí agrego los options de acuerdo a la base de datos.
                        });
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
                    });
```

Comment: Esto me suena a un problema de asincronía... Te recomiendo conseguir los datos primeros (todos) y una vez que los tengas todos utilizar  `.then` o `async/await` para agregar los nuevos elementos al `DOM`.

Comment: @FranAcuna Me puedes ayudar con ejemplo por favor

Comment: Disculpa, creo que estoy equivocado, no es un problema de asincronía.